# Use Symfony service in plain PHP

Tags: php, symfony

I'm trying to use a Symfony service in a legacy app.

An extract of the file:

```
<?php
use AppBundle\Services\HealthCoverageValidation\GenericCancellationRequest;
use AppBundle\Services\HealthCoverageValidation\Transaction;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;

/**
 * @var Composer\Autoload\ClassLoader
 */
$loader = require __DIR__.'/../app/autoload.php';
$kernel = new AppKernel('dev', true);

class Test extends \Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller {

    public function testAutorizacion() {
        global $kernel;
        $validator = $kernel->getContainer()->get('nano.services.health_coverage.validator');
```

But then `getContainer()` returns null. How can I workaround this?

Comment: there is a sample here https://stackoverflow.com/a/10178979/2078929

Comment: @MehmetSoylu Thank you, seems that only $kernel->boot() was missing

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use the Symfony 2 Container in a legacy app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10170989/how-to-use-the-symfony-2-container-in-a-legacy-app)